# SMPS Transformer affect RFID card

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, rfid

[image]

In my circuit, RFID card sometimes works sometimes not. it depends on how I put the card on RFID receiver. Usually it does not work when I put around the smps transformer. I guess SMPS transformer affect RFID card. I cannot change transformer and RFID receiver location. What do you suggest to remove SMPS transformer effect?

Comment: Get some flexible (and cutable) ferrite screening material from ferroxcube or Wurth and stick it on top of the SMPS.

Comment: Do you mean like this https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/laird-signal-integrity-products/MHLL6060-300/240-2791-ND/5230924

Comment: Yes, try it out. It may solve the problem and it may not but fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

If the SMPS really influences the RFID receiver, it is likely to be inductive coupling. This can be tested by removing the RFID receiver from its original place and using a short cable (3-5 inch) to space it away from the SMPS module.

If it is in fact inductive coupling, you can try to shield with ferrite. But I had a similar situation once where I just had to put some **copper tape** on the SMPS and all worked OK.